# Loop cut maintaining circular profile

Tags: modeling, mesh, geometry

Adding a loop cut to an object with a circular profile renders the object non-circular.  This is true for any object with a circular frame e.g. plain circles, UV-spheres, cylinders, cones, etc.

[image: Adding a loop cut to the cirlce makes it non-circular]

Top-left is the mesh of a plain circle with Subsurf modifier applied (bottom-left).  Notice how adding one additional vertex (top-right) makes the circle skewed (bottom-right).

**Is there a tool/transform/way to correct the circle?**

Knowing the solution to this should help solve the problem for all the aforementioned objects.  I tried selecting all points and applied the *To Sphere* transform in vain.  It didn't help.

I thought putting the vertex `r` radius away from the circle's centre like the rest of the vertices will help, looks like it doesn't.

Comment: if you subdivide and put the Smoothness at 1 in the Operator box it will keep the roundness, but of course if your object has a Subdivision Surface it will flat the curve as it will add virtual vertices in the middle of the new segments

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  Setting Smoothness to 1 did move the new vertex `r` radius away, but you're right! That isn't solving the problem since subsurf does flatten the curve and the skew doesn't vanish.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the verts are non-uniformly spaced, the result will always be deformed.
That's just how the [Catmull-Clark subdivision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catmull%E2%80%93Clark_subdivision_surface) works.

You can use *Cast Modifier* to correct the circular profile.
It can also be limited to a vertex group.

1. Add *Cast Modifier > Sphere*
2. Set *Factor = 1*
3. Done

[image]

Comment: Of course, this works but there seems to be no way to do it before the Subsurf modifier, which is usually the last in the modifier stack; so not always feasible but nevertheless a solution. Also this situation occurs only in a part of a complex mesh; I guess you could use vertex groups for that.

Comment: Also an explanation -- on why this happens and why it can't be fixed cleanly -- would be good.  I remember you giving an explanation about non-uniformly spaced vertices and the subsurf mod before the current edit.

Comment: Hello :). I added back the explanation. To learn more, read the [Catmull-Clark wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catmull%E2%80%93Clark_subdivision_surface). The *Cast modifier* has to be after the *Subdivision mod*, to 'deform' it back into a perfect circle.